# How to set a default Margin for all the controls on all my WPF windows?

Tags: wpf, window, controls, margin

I want to set a default Margin of 3 on all the controls I put on all my windows and be able to override this value just on a really few number of items.

I've seen some approaches like doing styles but then I need to style everything, I would prefer something than can be done for all the controls together. I've seen other things like the MarginSetter but looks like it does not traverse subpanels. I want the Margin only on the controls I put at the window, nothing to do with the borders or other things of the visual tree.

Looks something pretty basic to me. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: borders are controls. what's wring with using styles? If you use Wpf have a look at implicit styles - those which can be applied for a specific type (SL5 is supposed to have them too).

Comment: @Dmitry: what's wrong is that I will need to create a style for each and every control created by whoever that I use. This does not look as a great solution having in mind that all controls have base classes and that inheritance is used to avoid this kind of things (repeating stuff is always wrong when programming)

Comment: Did you read what I said - use implicit style - they get applied at a type rather than at an instance level.

Comment: @Dmitry: I was talking about creating a style for each and every type of control created until today or in the future.

Comment: I see, styles is the simplest and yest the right way to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only solution I can find is to apply the style to each of the controls you are using on the window (I know that's not quite what you want). If you're only using a few different control types it's not too onerous to do something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- One style for each *type* of control on the window -->
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="TextBox"/>
        <TextBlock Text="TextBlock"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Good luck...

Comment: Well, the thing is Windows Form had a default Margin value ... and everything always needs a margin set. I was looking for a generic solution to apply it to all my applications. Looks like I will have to create a style for each control ... that can hurt having in mind that I will need to maintain the damn thing forever.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a shortcoming in WPF. If I find a better solution I will post it here.

Answer (score 21):

You can link all of your Margin properties by referring to a "Thickness" defined in your resources. I just did this in a project...

```
<!-- somwhere in a resource-->
<Thickness  x:Key="CommonMargin" Left="0" Right="14" Top="6" Bottom="0" />

<!-- Inside of a Style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="MyStyle">
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource CommonMargin}" />
</Style>
<!-- Then call the style in a control -->
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />

<!-- Or directly on a Control -->
<Button Margin="{StaticResource CommonMargin}" />
```

The key for me was figuring out that Margin was defined by "Thickness". Let me know if that's clear enough or if you need me to put it in a fully working XAML example.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply margin in your buttons style. And when you use buttons with this style in StackPanel wpf will apply need spacing.
for example
define in resourcedictionary or whatever:

```
 <Style x:Key="myButtonStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
....
</Style>
```

then in yor StackPanel xaml definition:

```
<StackPanel>
   <Border BorderThickness="0"/>
   <Button x:Name="VertBut1" Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"      Content="Button1"/>
   <Button x:Name="VertBut2" Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"      Content="Button2"/>
   <Button x:Name="VertBut3" Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"      Content="Button3"/>
</StackPanel>
```

regards
Georgi

Comment: is it possible to add the style to the stackpanel and have that style propagated downwards to all child elements?